# connecting two LAN network using outdoor wireless antenna

Tags: wireless-networking, vlan, antenna

I want to connect two building using outdoor wireless antenna ,
assume that I have two buildings like below picture and I want to connect these building together,
[image]
 what equipments I need for doing this,  what's is easy solution for do that?
**thanks in your advise**

Comment: How far apart and where are they?

Comment: for instance 15KM.

Comment: A directional antenna with a 20 dBi gain @ 2.4 Ghz should work.

Answer (score 0):

For that exact purpose, and considering you specified range, you can use the Nanostation 5 series provided by  [Ubiquiti Networks](https://www.ubnt.com/airmax/nanostationm/) .

There may be others that offer similar devices, but those are confirmed to be working. I used them a few years back and they proved very reliable.